# Angular auth guard nested async call

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, fork-join

I have an issue conerning my auth guard where I'm trying to call two async http request, and then after it's successfuly done I want to do a third one to get one last info before I let user access the page.

Here is my code so far :

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {

    if (this.recruteurService.getUserInfo() &&
      this.recruteurService.getIndividuPro() &&
      this.recruteurService.getEtablissement()) {
      return true;
    }

    return forkJoin(
      this.recruteurService.rechercherUserInfo(),
      this.recruteurService.rechercherIndividuProfessionnel())
      .mergeMap(([userInfo, individuPro]) => {
        if (userInfo && individuPro) {
          this.recruteurService.setUserInfo(userInfo);
          this.recruteurService.setIndividuPro(individuPro);
        } else {
          return false;
        }

        return this.recruteurService.rechercherEtablissementParIdRce(individuPro.etablissements[0]).map(
          (etablissement: Etablissement) => {
            if (etablissement) {
              this.recruteurService.setEtablissement(etablissement);
              return of(true);
            }
            return of(false);
          });
      });
  }
```

The problem is that I'm getting an error :

> ERROR in src/app/guard/initialization.guard.ts(32,17): error TS2345:
>   Argument of type '([userInfo, individuPro]: [any, Individu]) => false
>   | Observable>' is not assignable to parameter of
>   type '(value: [any, Individu], index: number) =>
>   ObservableInput>'.   Type 'false |
>   Observable>' is not assignable to type
>   'ObservableInput>'.
>       Type 'false' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput>'.

But I can't figure out what's the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You defined `canActivate() => boolean` but then you're returning `forkJoin()` which is `Observable<boolean>` if I understand your code correctly.

The `canActivate` method can return `boolean` or `Observable<boolean>` thus `boolean | Observable<boolean>` return type, see https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate.

You might want to make `canActivate(...): boolean | Observable<boolean>` or just use only `canActivate(...): Observable<boolean>` and then return `return of(true);`.

Comment: actually it was boolean | Observable<boolean> but I removed it to try and see what happen. But still have the error. The error above is on this live `.mergeMap(([userInfo, individuPro]) => {`

Comment: You still have `return false;` inside `mergeMap`. The callbacks needs to return an Observable eg. `return of(false);`

Comment: I changed it and I got another error way more complciated :

`Type 'Observable<boolean> | Observable<Observable<boolean>>' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<boolean>'.
    Type 'Observable<Observable<boolean>>' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<boolean>'.
      Type 'Observable<Observable<boolean>>' is not assignable to type 'ArrayLike<boolean>'.
        Property 'length' is missing in type 'Observable<Observable<boolean>>'.`

Comment: You're returning Observable of Observables of booleans, but I can't tell you where because I don't have your code.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I managed to find a solution using the operator flatMap on the second observable stream :

`return this.recruteurService.rechercherEtablissementParIdRce(individuPro.etablissements[0]).flatMap(`

> flatMap - It basically merges an observable sequence of observable
>   sequences into a single observable sequence.

Thank to this doc : [Map vs FlatMap](https://namitamalik.github.io/Map-vs-FlatMap/)